# Re-organise Excel w/ text cells

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I do understand the title may be slightly confusing since I don't exactly know how to describe what I am attempting to do.

This is the problem: I have an .xls file that looks like this:

This is my current excel file:

[image]

It's a long, long list with song numbers and the biblebooks they are referring to. So, for instance, in verse 1, the reference is Gen. 12:1-9. In verse 2, two biblebooks are referenced, namely 1 Kor. 2:9-15, and Ef. 4:1-6. If the abbreviations don't make sense to you it's because they're in Dutch.

I want it to look like this:

[image: image2]

I want the biblebooks to be organised according to what verses they are references in instead of the other way around. I want to see which verses are referenced to in what biblebooks (see the picture).

Some of the biblebooks are referenced to in multiple songs (as you can see in the picture): Psalm 90 is referenced to in verse 19 ánd 20.

I thought this to be simple but as it turns out it's trickier than I'd hoped it would be. I did promise someone that I would do this (and I thought it'd be a simple matter of transposing the columns and rows) but I've been going at it for about an hour now, with the help of Google, and I'm still getting nowhere.

So any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this *'gimme teh codez'* request as off-topic because it is patently inadequate as an [SO](http://goo.gl/whPhMk) question and could in no way benefit any future viewer. The OP has not demonstrated even a rudimentary knowledge of the platform; has shown no original effort beyond a list of requirements; and has only supplied sample data in the form of remote links to images. This question is worthless to [SO](http://goo.gl/whPhMk) on every level that a question is measured by.

Comment: Believe me, I do empathise with your opinion. But, please allow me to rebuke. I am not a programmer; in terms that would show most overlap with the subject-matter of this forum, I'd describe myself as a statistician. Like you are now, I used to participate on fora devoted to my fields of expertise (most notably, psychology). And I had very similar sentiments. After all, any forum that has an easy access point (e.g. FB log-in) has a lot of posters that ask stupid questions phrased in uninformed ways. I had to learn a long time ago that this is simply the way an on-line forum operates.

Comment: In my case I always figured people should think logically for themselves before asking unspecified questions demanding some sort of psychological counselling. A fellow moderator pointed out to me that going 'round demanding that from people turned most threads sideways, and would end up being counter-productive. And he was right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your original worksheet, `select` the range you want and `copy` it:
 [image: table]

Then `transpose` it into a new sheet:

[image: transpose]

Hit `Alt + D + P` to bring up the Pivot Table Menu and `select` "Multiple Consolidation Ranges" then click "Next":

[image: pivot table menu]

`Select` "I will create the page fields" and click "Next":

[image: pivot table menu2]

`Select` the entire transposed range and click "Add" then click "Next":

[image: pivot table menu3]

Click "Finish" to create the Pivot Table in a new worksheet:

[image: pivot table menu4]

Double-click on the grand total cell of the Pivot Table to un-pivot the data:

[image: pivot table results]

Your un-pivoted table will now appear on a new tab:

[image: unpivoted]

`Filter` out the blanks and your data is now converted:

[image: converted]

Comment: Very much appreciated!

Comment: @GideonSinke It's a bit circuitous but is better than doing by hand

Comment: @GideonSinke If the solution worked for you, feel free to mark the question as answered. Thanks!